# Prove that $\lambda(E \cap (-x_0, x_0)) > \lambda(E) - \epsilon$ for some $x_0$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $E$ is a measurable subset of $\Bbb R$ with finite measure and that $\epsilon > 0$. 
Prove that there must be a number $x_0$ such that $m(E \cap (-x_0 , x_0 )) > m(E) - \epsilon$.

I understand what the proof is asking for, and I know this is possible, but I'm unsure how to start the proof. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $\varphi(x)=m(E\cap(-x,x))$ for $x>0$, then $\varphi(x)\rightarrow m(E)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. So some $x$ must be $\varphi(x)>m(E)-\epsilon$.